# 'currentURL()' not working as expected in ember's tests after upgrade

Tags: testing, ember.js

Tests using the 'currentURL()' started to randomly fail when the URL changes more than 2 times (in the same test case).

This started after the application was updated (ember-cli) from the version 1.X to the ~2.16.2.

I've tried (With no positive results):

1. Updating the `ember-cli-qunit`.
2. Using `import { currentURL } from '@ember/test-helpers';`.

**Update:**

Here is an example of one of those tests (Marked as 'Flaky' the problematic parts):

```
test('My test', async () => {
    await visit('/testing-page-1');
    const selectSortId = find('[data-test-select="my-select"]');
    equal(selectSortId.val(), "1", "Wrong selection,...");

    await selectSortId.val(3).trigger('change');
    equal(currentURL(), '/testing-page-2'); // All good here

    const firstEditButton = find('[data-test-button="1"]');
    await click(firstEditButton);
    equal(currentURL(), '/testing-page-3'); // Flaky

    const secondButton = find('[data-test-button="2"]');
    await click(secondButton);
    equal(currentURL(), '/testing-page-4') // Flaky
});
```

Comment: When you say “randomly fail” you mean it’s returning incorrect information?

Comment: Yes @BuckDoyle
Sometimes returns the previous URL, sometimes the URL missing some query params and sometimes the right one.

Comment: do you maybe not wait for readyness? How do you trigger the transition?

Comment: Hi @Lux, I have updated the question showing an example of my tests.

Comment: it’s sad but sometimes a sprinkling of `await settled();` can help 

Comment: Thanks for sharing the idea @BuckDoyle, but in this case it seems not to be a matter of waiting. 
Al tried waitUntil currentURL() === '/testing-page-3', with a decent timeout, logging the current URL every time, but it just does not grab the right one.

Comment: hmm, mysterious… if you insert `await this.pauseTest()` is it indeed on the route you would expect?

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this, and it was not an issue with the ember test suit...

There was an Ember.hash in the app, one of those calls had some data needed to populate our urls with the some parameters.

In production, the call with the data was noticeable slower than the others, so we luckily got the data.
In testing mode, we had this data being overwritten by the other calls.

i.e; it was a matter of a bad design needed to be refactored...